# as was validated by other authors

Tags: sentence-construction

Is the use of "as was validated" in the following sentence correct grammatically and conceptually? If it is not , kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

> Fig. 6 displays the comparison between the present numerical results
>   (CTB) with the experimental results of Curran and Gato [11] and
>   numerical results [12-14], as was validated by other authors [12-14].

Comparsion=Validation

Comment: "as (was) validated ..." is grammatically correct. What is most confusing, and deserves more attention than that structure, is the "comparison between ... with ... and ... and ..." construction.

Comment: Why not? Rather than just ask if some words are correct (that's really proofreading), why not tell us why you think it might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Fig. 6 displays the comparison between the present numerical results
>   (CTB) with the experimental results of Curran and Gato [11] and
>   numerical results [12-14], as was validated by other authors [12-14].

**as was validated** is equivalent to **it was validated ealier** and is perfectly valid. Here it refers to the *Figure #6* that displays the comparison.

You can make many other examples of your own:

- The sea indeed was cold, as was mentioned in the news.
- The dinosaurs weren't the biggest animals that ever lived on Earth, as was belived by most people.

Comment: @user19061 your example is fine, as was validated by SovereignSun in his answer above ;)

Comment: I only don't think "as was validated" is equivalent to "the way it was validated".

Comment: @Gustavson _"Just"_ and _"only"_ are not synonymous. We say _"I just don't think…"_, and not _"I only don't think…"_.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Thanks, but I didn't mean to say *just* or *simply*. I meant to say *only* to indicate that I agree with the answer in general terms but **only** disagree with the semantic equivalence provided.